# parse getInBackground throws InvalidKeyName exception

Tags: android, mongodb, parse-platform

I am trying to migrate my Parse app to MongoDB. I have got MangoDB up up and running and connected to pars.com server as described in parse.com/docs/server/guide#migrating.

Now I am trying to connect to my Parse server from Android Parse SDK version is 1.13.0.

Initialization is:

```
    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
            .applicationId("apid")
            .clientKey("key")
            .server("http ://server:1337")
            .enableLocalDataStore()
            .build());
```

GET method works fine from command line:

> curl -X GET   -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: "   -H "X-Parse-Master-Key: "   -G   http : //serverip:1337/classes/New/EXOIesqEa3              {"objectId":"EXOIesqEa3","Name":"Third","createdAt":"2016-01-31T14:24:18.950Z","

However, it dose not work in Android SDK, as it uses POST instead of GET with body, something like:

> curl -X POST   -H "key"   -H "Content-Type: application/json"   -d '{"where":"{\"objectId\":\"iXMRHnQN1a\"}","_method":"GET"}'   http://server:1337/classes/GameScore1

Parse server response is InvalidKeyName exception: {"code":105,"error":"invalid key name: 0"}.

Can someone help here to figure out why it returns this InvalidKeyName exception?

Please note that:

> curl -X POST   -H "X-Parse-Application-key"   -H "Content-Type: application/json"   -d '{"_method":"GET"}'   http://server:1337/classes/GameScore1
>   works fine.